# PC freezes randomly but streaming audio works

Tags: freeze

It happens on my both operating systems (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04) and also did happen on another linux distributions so its probably hardware issue. Mostly it happens when I switch between apps/browser tabs. Also important to mention that keyboard and mouse do not respond but power supply continues

My config:

- AMD Ryzen 3 2200G
- SSD 2.5" SATA-III Patriot 120Gb Burst PBU120GS25SSDR
- MB MSI B450M PRO-M2 Soc-AM4
- DDR IV 8Gb PC-19200 2400MHz G.Skill Aegis (x2)

any thoughts about how can I troubleshoot that?

Comment: As you note - probably hardware.  Update BIOS and ALL drivers. Restart and run the computer manufacturer's hardware test application.

Comment: Updated the bios to latest version. I'll see for a while if anything has changed. Thanks